# How to implement Random.nextDouble() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, random

I am using Math.floor((Math.random() * max-min)+min) for random number generation, 
what is the difference between this function and random.nextDouble() ?
How to implement random.nextDouble in Javascript?

Comment: This random.nextDouble() method is present in java. But i need the same functionality or output in Javascript

Comment: Well, Javascript does not have precisely the same numeric types as Java.  But `Math.random` itself is likely as close as you'll get, returning a uniformly distributed random numeric value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
var min = 99; var max = 101; Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //random int from min to max (not including)
```

2. int (32 bits) [-2^(32-1), +2^(32-1)+1 ] ([-2147483648, 2147483647]);
3. double (64 bits) [-4.9e-324 , 1.7e+308];

Need to convert int to double.